# How to submit a paper to Bulletin of Number Theory and Related Topics

Tags: publications, journals, publishers

The journal **Bulletin of Number Theory and Related Topics** (*Boletín de teoría de números y temas conexos*) does not seem to have its own website, from where one can obtain article/paper submission details and instructions.  (I am interested in submitting a paper to this journal for possible publication.)

I did find the following [search facility](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000681926) for the journal in the Hathi Trust Digital Library.  But then again, no mention is made as to the submission details/instructions that I require.

In Chapter 1 of the book [**New Visual Perspectives on Fibonacci Numbers**](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=DMDUCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=Aldo%20Peretti%20Bulletin%20of%20Number%20Theory%20and%20Related%20Topics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1xfKvgOLTAhWMP48KHba_AfUQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=Aldo%20Peretti%20Bulletin%20of%20Number%20Theory%20and%20Related%20Topics&f=false) (*Introductory Remarks [by K T Atanassov]*), the author mentions (in page 4) that "[he] sent some [of his results] to **Professor Aldo Peretti**, who published them in *Bulletin of Number Theory and Related Topics*".  (It appears that Professor Peretti is the Editor (?) of the said journal.)  However, when I try to Google for Professor Peretti's e-mail address, no helpful results are returned.  Additionally, I tried to search for Peretti's papers in [the arXiv](https://arxiv.org) (if any), and found none, and therefore was unable to get hold of his e-mail address.

I am posting this question here in the hopes that someone with better Internet search skills can enlighten me.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to publish there?

Comment: I just want to give it a shot.  I have some papers containing a few (original) ideas in number theory that they might deem worthy of getting published there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need a time machine.  According to [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/bulletin-of-number-theory-and-related-topics-boletin-de-teoria-de-numeros-y-temas-conexos/oclc/851320240) and [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/journaldoc.html?id=4292), it appears this journal ceased publication sometime around 1991 or 1992.